# What is the way to update solr schema using code in sitecore 10.3?

Tags: solr

I need to update Solr schema for text highlighting using code.

What is the way to update Solr schema using code in Sitecore 10.3?

Since **'SolrProvider.GetHelper is obsolete'**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's all described in Sitecore documentation here:

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/platform-administration-and-architecture/add-custom-fields-to-a-solr-schema.html

In shortcut:

- You need to create your own `ISchemaPopulateHelper` implementation, best by overriding `SchemaPopulateHelper`, e.g.

```
public class CustomPopulateHelper : SchemaPopulateHelper
{
    public CustomPopulateHelper(SolrSchema schema) : base(schema)
    {
    }
    ...
}
```

- And your own factory like:

```
public class CustomPopulateHelperFactory : IPopulateHelperFactory
{
    public ISchemaPopulateHelper GetPopulateHelper(SolrSchema solrSchema)
    {
        return new CustomPopulateHelper(solrSchema);
    }
}
```

- Then register the factory in patch file:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <contentSearch.PopulateSolrSchema>
        <processor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Pipelines.PopulateSolrSchema.PopulateFields, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
       <param type="Documentation.Examples.CustomPopulateHelperFactory, Documentation.Examples" patch:instead="*[@type='Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Factories.DefaultPopulateHelperFactory']"/>
     </processor>
      </contentSearch.PopulateSolrSchema>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It is helpful can you please suggest how can we get index name in this implementation

Comment: I answered your another question with detailed explanation. You can mark this answer as correct if it answered this question.